# Can ping/ssh through LAN but not with Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ssh, router, ping

I have bought a new D-link Wi-Fi modem recently, and I have connected one Linux system through LAN and another system through Wi-Fi.  I can't ping the host which is connected to the LAN from the Wi-Fi host, but if I connect both to LAN, that works fine. What settings do I need to change?

Edited:

1. I am trying using IP addresses.
2. Please find the IP information below. I got this from the `ifconfig` command, by connecting both the LAN and Wi-Fi at the same time.

   ```
     eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:b9:00:31:23  
               inet addr:192.168.1.35  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
               inet6 addr: fe80::226:b9ff:fe00:3150/64 Scope:Link
               UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
               RX packets:1001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
               TX packets:1984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
               collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
               RX bytes:332948 (332.9 KB)  TX bytes:237770 (237.7 KB)
               Interrupt:17

     wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d6:14:35:44  
               inet addr:192.168.1.34  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
               inet6 addr: fe80::224:d6ff:fe14:350a/64 Scope:Link
               UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
               RX packets:8328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
               TX packets:19806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
               collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
               RX bytes:2777900 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:2298641 (2.2 MB)
   ```
3. I am using DHCP only (not static).
4. Even `nmap` is not showing the host 192.168.1.33.  :(

   ```
   jeshwanth@jeshwanth:~$ nmap -sP 192.168.1.*

   Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-03 23:31 IST
   Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
   Host is up (0.015s latency).
   Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.34
   Host is up (0.00081s latency).
   Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 16.02 seconds
   ```

Comment: Sounds like you have set up different subnets but we can't help unless you actually show us some settings. Are you pinging by hostname or by IP address? Please [edit] your question to answer this (do not answer in a comment) and also show us the settings of each connection, including the IP address, gateway and netmask. Also explain if you are assigning IP addresses automatically via DHCP or if they are static.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, is the `ifconfig` output from the host that fails when connected by WiFi? Your `nmpap` output shows that the wifi IP (192.168.1.34) is found. You seem to expect it to find 33, which machine is that?

Comment: Yes the output is of the host (Wifi) which is trying to connect. 34 is my machine where I am executing nmap, 33 is may Raspberry pi :). And found the solution here http://superuser.com/questions/136031/ssh-no-route-to-host?rq=1 , I switched on "User Isolation". Its working fine now :). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you post what you did as an answer and accept it when you get the chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution in [ssh - no route to host](https://superuser.com/questions/136031/ssh-no-route-to-host?rq=1), what I did was, login to my modem (in my case 192.168.1.1 through any browser). Select Advanced Tab, then go to wireless setting, In SSID settings changed **User Isolation** from **off** to **on**, restart the modem. Now you can ping/ssh to LAN connected host through Wifi connected host :).
I am using [D-Link DSL-2750U Wireless N ADSL2+ 4-Port Wi-Fi Router](http://www.amazon.in/D-Link-DSL-2750U-Wireless-4-Port-Router/dp/B007O7J026/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386134940&sr=8-1-fkmr1&keywords=d-link+wireless+modem)

[image: Advanced >> Wireless Setting]

Comment: Great!! Just the thing I have also been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and a similar solution.  I was connected via wireless Netgear on wlan0 where it would not ping the router even though dhclient worked (after dhclient -r).

I had to check the "Allow guest access to My Local Network" checkbox in my router (also Netgear).  Then I could ping the router.